# How can I decrease the height of an element top to bottom rather than the default bottom to top?

Tags: html, image, css, height

I have an image that represents a gauge in a game I'm making and, from testing it, I realized that decreasing the height takes away from the bottom rather than the top. I'd like to invert this somehow. Is there anyway to?

Comment: Well, I'd suggest use any image editor to crop it rather than doing it dynamically.

Comment: Can we see some code? You have this tagged as a css issue - is this a background image we're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the value of the y-position for the `background-position` property of the element to be a set distance above the image.

For example, if your background-image file is 100px tall and you set the div for it to be 30px tall, then the y-position of your background-image would need to be 70 pixels above the top of the div for the pixels to appear to vanish from the top of the image.

HTML:

```
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#my-div {
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url( 'my-image.png' );
  background-position: 0px -70px;
}
```